# Z axis stopped part way through print

Tags: marlin, ultimaker-cura, z-axis, anet-a8

I got an Anet A8 for Christmas.

I am trying to print a calibration tower and the z axis stops lifting at approximately 100mm.

I checked that the gantry is able to travel along the full length of the threaded rods, and while resetting the bed height I noticed that the LCD display showed the extruder height above the bed.  It reads 0 at home (good) but goes back to zero when I manually turn the rods so that the gantry goes above the heigh at which the print stopped.

Any thoughts on what to check? I am double checking all the mechanical bits (connection to stepper coupling, ease of turning, etc...).

My slicer is Cura 3.1.

Comment: Can you move higher in Z  via the  "position - Z-axis"  menu on the printer?  DId you make sure that the current  z-limits for the printer volume in Cura are set correctly?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Cura won't produce any Gcode if the model doesn't fit entirely in the print volume, so I don't think that should be the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two issues:

- While cutting the cables to size, I made the cable for the z-axis too short.
- In Cura the y height reset to 100mm rather than the 240mm I had earlier specified.  I assume the G-code I used was sliced with the wrong settings.